# When will the random bit sequence start to repeat in pseudo random number generator

Tags: cryptography, random, discrete-logarithms

Let's say we have the Blum-Micali pseudorandom number generator.

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%E2%80%93Micali_algorithm):

- Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$.
- Let $x_0$ be a seed, and let $x_{i+1} = g^{x_i}\ \bmod{\ p}$.
- The $i$-th output of the algorithm is 1 if 
  $x_i < \frac{p-1}{2}$. Otherwise the output is 0.

When will the random bits generated start repeating in this case? I have manually tried some examples but could not find a pattern there.

- For p = 19, g = 3, $x_o$ = 4, bit sequence start repeating after 10 bits
- For p = 19, g = 3, $x_o$ = 3, bit sequence start repeating after 8 bits
- For p = 7, g = 3, $x_o$ = 3, bit sequence start repeating after 3 bits
- For p = 11, g = 6, $x_o$ = 4, bit sequence start repeating after 4 bits
- For p = 11, g = 6, $x_o$ = 9, bit sequence start repeating after 6 bits

Is there a relationship with the size of $p$, $g$ and $x_0$ and the period when the bits start repeating themselves?

Answer (score 1):

If you're unlucky in your choice of $p, g, x_0$, you might even have a period of $1$.
For example, $2$ is a primitive root mod $13$, and $2^{10} \equiv 10 \mod 13$.

Comment: So, can we have a general formula in regard of $p$, $g$ and $x_0$ ?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple formula.  I think that for large primes $p$, most primitive roots $g$ will have some $x_0$ such that $g^{x_0} \equiv x_0 \mod p$.